# libproj not loaded while installing sumo on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, flow-project

I was going through the Flow installation and when I typed `sumo --version` into the terminal I got the following error message:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.13.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/apple/sumo_binaries/bin/sumo
Reason: image not found`

I've tried reinstalling sumo but the problem persisted.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a fix for the problem.

Type the following into the terminal:

ln -s /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.15.dylib /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.13.dylib

Open up the directory mentioned above and make sure both libraries show (even if one of them is a shortcut) and rerun the sumo installation.

Note: you may have to change the paths depending on where your libproj.15.dylib is located.